# how to use cakePHP for a large web system

Tags: cakephp, structure

I'm looking for a way to structure my project folder under source directory with cakePHP as the following:

- src

  - Controller

    - Admin

      - UsersController.php
      - MenusController.php
      - ProfileController.php
    - Production

      - ReceptionController.php
      - a lot more controllers...
    - A lot more folders...

      - with a lote more controllers.

**¿Is there a way to achieve this?** or I just miss understood all the framework workflow?

PS. I wanted to do the same over my views, layout and model folder.

Should I do this with routing? Is there an easy way?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) requires exactly the same structure that you have shown. So use that.

Comment: i know this is not the platform for this but thanks for contributing for community , i have used your cakephp plugins a lot. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version you are using:

If you are using cakephp 2.x you should use the plugin approach [Plugin docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

If you are using cakephp 3.x it simple just create the structure you have created .

From the structure that you have provided, its cakephp 3.x that you are using create the mentioned folder structure and you are good to go. access it by `admin/users/login` or use ADmad's solution.